# Unable to set network mode host in azure container

Tags: networking, azure, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up network_mode: host in my docker-compose file in scope of my azure web app for container. But it looks like this setting is ignored according to logs. There is no --network parameter passed in "docker run" command created automatically by azure.

Could you please help understand why? Is that because of limitations of azure? Or it is impossible at all in any cloud provider?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a limitation of the cloud, it's a limitation of the service you are trying to use.  Azure provided a few options to host containers.  Azure Web App for Containers, Azure Container Instances, and Azure Kubernetes Services.  From your question, it looks like you are going the Web App for Containers approach.  The `--network` parameter is ignored in [Azure Web App for Containers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations).

**Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)** manages your hosted Kubernetes environment, making it quick and easy to deploy and manage containerized applications without container orchestration expertise. It also eliminates the burden of ongoing operations and maintenance by provisioning, upgrading, and scaling resources on demand, without taking your applications offline.  AKS will allow you to setup networking, here is our documentation:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network